# Shrink wrap a "max-sized" image

Tags: html, css

Setting `max-width` and `max-height` to 100% for an image does what's intended and scales the image to fit it's container with aspect-ratio intact. However, I need to achieve the same thing but with an extra container kept tight around the image (**to be able to position other stuff relative to the image**).

I'm looking for non-JS solutions and mark-up semantics is not an issue since this is for an app. (tables would be ok). Also image dimensions can be considered known.

Another way to describe what I want: Make an image always fit inside the body and display a border around it (not using the trivial solution of putting a border on the image itself)

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzc4m/) showing the problem. I gave the image an `0.5` opacity to make the yellow container show through. The objective is to have the container always the same size as the image. Ie. the image will always have a yellow tint but no other yellow areas should be visible. Note: I'm not trying to achieve any coloring effects it's just an illustration of the problem.

Comment: do you have a screenshot or a diagram available?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, http://jsfiddle.net/xmarcos/K4dHr/

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/xmarcos/K4dHr/4/

Comment: Negative. Works width-wise but scrolls horizontally when image is taller than view-port. Still, I'm starting to accept that this is the best that can be done. Frustrating though, when just fitting the image works so well you'd think a simple wrapper would be possible...

Comment: Ok, sorry for being picky, but.. the container remains at 100% width when image shrinks. Which means I can't position stuff relative the image-width which is a requirement. Big thanx for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Here, this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/vzc4m/1/

You don't need to have a max-height around your `<div>` because it will stretch to the dimensions of its inner elements if you set it as `display: inline-block`. Forcing the `<img>` to have `display: block` will ensure that there isn't any extra space added around element inside container, unless you specify it (using margin).